# Serialization exception in .NET: System.InvalidOperationException: You must implement a default accessor on System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1

Tags: .net, generics, serialization

All I am trying to do is

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stack<int>));
```

and I get the following at runtime:

`System.InvalidOperationException`: You must implement a default accessor on 
`System.Collections.Generic.Stack``1 [[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it inherits from ICollection.

Am I not supposed to serialize the `Stack<int>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the Stack class does not have a default accessor (by index for example) you cannot serialize it with that method.

I would suggest copying your stack to a List then serializing the list.

```
List<int> serializableLIst = new List<int>( myStack );
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSeralizer(typeof(List<int>));
```

See if that doesn't work better.

Comment: It does work, thanks! It would be interesting to know why the framework designers decided not to support serialization on the Stack<T> itself...

Comment: They do not provide the default accessor for the stack.  You cannot say x = myStack[3] for example.  The Stack operates differently than a normal collection so the accessor is not implemented on it.