# .NET XmlSerializer and generic SortedSet properties

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

I have a .net config class:

```
public class Config {
  public SortedSet<string> SiteURLs { get; private set; }

  public Config() {
    SiteURLs = new SortedSet<string>();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to send it out to an XmlSerializer, which fails with "There was an error reflecting type". Adding [XmlIgnore] to the SiteURLs property allows the class to be serialized.

Do I actually have to write custom serialization code here? The docs indicate that as long as the property implements ICollection and provides an 'Add' method, it should work. Perhaps I am missing some other necessary configuration.

Examples of how to serialize/deserialize generics with .NET all seem to have custom serialization all over the place.

Comment: In .NET 2.0, you can't XML serialize an IDictionary<> member. Maybe you're facing the same problem with the SortedSet.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398642/.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change setter to public.

`XmlSerializer` does not handle private or protected fields.

Comment: If it was the point, `Config` would serialize but without its member, but it's not the case, an exception is raised.

Comment: Try to look to the inner exception. What is it saying?

Comment: .NET newby, I am. InnerException is "You must implement a default accessor on System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it inherits from ICollection."}. Too bad SortedSet doesn't implement such an accessor. Generic collections of simple types are pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//
//some example class
//
public class Music: IComparable<Music>
{
    public Music() { }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Music other)
    {
        if (Author == other.Author)
        {
            return Name.ToUpper().CompareTo(other.Name.ToUpper());
        }
        else
        {
            return Author.ToUpper().CompareTo(other.Author.ToUpper());
        }
    }
}

//
// that is to deserialize
//
var musics = new SortedSet<Music>();
var mPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\j.txt";
if (File.Exists(mPath))
{
    File.Copy(mPath, mPath.Replace(".txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".txt"));
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Music>));
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(mPath))
    {
        musics = new SortedSet<Music>((List<Music>)ser.Deserialize(sr));
    }
}

//
// that is to serialize
//
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Music>));

using (var wri = new StreamWriter(mPath))
{
    ser.Serialize(wri, musics.ToList());
}
```